# How long does it take for an IP to be removed from the exit nodes list?

Tags: exit-relays, network-health

How long does it take for an IP listed here (https://collector.torproject.org/recent/exit-lists/) to be removed from the list after a node has been shut down?

Is it normal to have to wait more than a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes about 1 day for an IP address to be removed from the most recent exit list, but that directory contains exit lists published in the past 3 days.  So, that's 4 days for an IP address to disappear from that directory after stopping the relay.  However, there's also https://collector.torproject.org/archive/exit-lists/ which archives exit addresses forever, though in compressed form and hence probably harder to process.